# Is there a way of adding a LOT of Facebook like buttons to a page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I've tried using the standard [Facebook like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). I require about 50 like buttons (that number may grow) on my page. The problem is that the second I add more than a few, it drastically slows down my page. If I show all 50 like buttons, the page is practically unoperable, the browser refuses to scroll, freezes and gives "Not responding" warnings etc.

I assume this is because the like buttons weren't made to be displayed multiple times on one page, and it does a **LOT** of redundant work for every added button. I've seen it be done though, so I'm wondering: **is there some special way of displaying lots of Facebook like buttons on one page? I'm talking tens, perhaps hundreds.**

Thanks

Comment: I've done this - it really, really slows down your page. All these iframes opening and making requests creates quite a lot of traffic.

Comment: 50 like buttons on one page seems a bit many?

Comment: To give you an example, all the boxes on [this page](http://honstreams.com/) should have one like button each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I would recommend doing this.  One is to render a fake Facebook button (static image) and then on hover, dynamically load the real Facebook like button to replace the image.    The other is to use one of the various jquery scrolling plugins to load the Facebook like buttons as the content becomes visible on the page.  TechCrunch.com has lots of like buttons on their home page without performance issues (they are doing the second option I listed).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must implement your own FB link, example:

```
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=your-url" class="someFBClass" ><span class=icon></span> Facebook</a>
```

[real example](http://www.groupon.com.ar/deals/hoteles)

You have to add some css to make the link look FB link.

Comment: he asks for a way to implement a LIKE-button.. not a share button ;)

Comment: Keep in mind though that you are not allowed to create any facebook 'look-a-like' buttons as that's against their T & C

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing using the FB.XFBML.parse method.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

This allows you to render the like as and when you need them, each just the one in the veiwport.

Also to make sure, your not loading the facebook javascript SDK (the old XFBML way) for each like button?